# Strange result with

Tags: sqlite

When i run this as my first commend i get an exception an error `near "last_insert_rowid"`. This is referring to the last last_insert_rowid();. If i set the curser to the line command.CommandText = and run it again it is fine.

What gives? The last_insert_rowid seems to be working properly why doesnt the last_insert_rowid after the 2nd insert work.

I tried moving last_insert_rowid() to after the execute and i still get an error. What gives?

```
        using (var trans = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            command.CommandText = 
                "INSERT INTO link_list(link, status, hash_type, hash_id) " +
                "VALUES(@link, @status, @hash_type, @hash_id);" +
                "INSERT INTO active_dl(linkId, orderNo) " +
                "VALUES(last_insert_rowid(), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM active_dl)); last_insert_rowid();";
            command.Parameters.Add("@link", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = link;
            command.Parameters.Add("@status", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = SiteBase.Status.none;
            command.Parameters.Add("@hash_type", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = 0;
            command.Parameters.Add("@hash_id", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = 0;
            int rowid = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
        }
```

Comment: Question title lacks specificity: "Strange result with" what?

Comment: On as side note, doesn't ExecuteNonQuery return the number of rows affected? If  you want to return the last inserted id you would have to use ExecuteScalar I would have thought.

Comment: Caelum: Oops. The syntax error has blinded me from that. Thats one less bug to take me by surprise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the last last_insert_rowid() there? After the second insert you call last_insert_rowid with no select or anything to identify what you want to do with it.

You would have to put a select in front of it to retrieve the value wouldn't you?

Comment: putting a select in front work. I wonder why it didnt give me an error when i moved the breakpoint up and ran it the second time (thats inconsistent)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute 2 sql commands in the one statement.  You'll need to split the 2 statements up into 2 calls and return the inserted id from the first statement.

An alternative suggestion is a stored procedure but I don't think sqlite supports these.